# object comparison in inheriance

Tags: c++, operators

In the below code comparing two objects using == shows different output than comparing two character pointer. Please help me on this how it works.

```
 #include <iostream>

 class A
 {
 public:
   A() : m_i(0) { }

 protected:
   int m_i;
 };

 class B
 {
 public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

 protected:
    double m_d;
 };

 class C
      : public A
       , public B
 {
  public:
      C() : m_c('a') { }

  private:
      char m_c;
  };

  int main()
  {
    C c;
    A *pa = &c;
    B *pb = &c;

    const int x = (pa == &c) ? 1 : 2;
    const int y = (pb == &c) ? 3 : 4;
    const int z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) ==   reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)) ? 5 : 6;

    std::cout << x << y << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

output:
136

Why value of y is 3 where as value of z is 6. What exactly happening here.
Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const int y = (pb == &c) ? 3 : 4;
```

is equivalent to using

```
B *pb2 = &c;
const int y = (pb == bp2) ? 3 : 4;
```

When `&c` is compared with a `B*`, it is automatically cast to `B*`, which offsets the address of `c` to match the `B` part of `C`. That's why the expression `(pb == &c)` evaluates to `true`.

However, `pa` and `pb` are different addresses. Hence, when you compare their values using

```
(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) ==   reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb))
```

the value of that expression will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using multiple inheritance. In this scenario, when you create an instance of Derived class typically what happens is :

- Enough memory is reserved to hold data for all the base classes and the Derived class.
- Order in which the data of base classes in laid out in memory is the inheritance order you specify for Derived class. For your case:

  `class C: public A, public B`

  the memory layout of object looks like: A data members, B data members followed by C data members.

In your case pa and pb are actually pointing to different addresses but y is assigned a value 3 because of implicit conversion during comparison. But by doing reinterpret cast to a char* you are taking away the information that allows the compiler to do implicit casting. Instead a plain pointer comparison is done and the result is false.

If you do
 `C* pc = &c;`

and check the value of pc in debugger, you will notice that it is the same as pa which highlights the above point.

Answer (score 0):

You passing address of object 'c' to pointer 'pa' of class A & to pointer 'pb' of class B.

As 'pa' && 'pb' holds same memory referenced to object 'c' of Class C , so expression for variable x & y is true.

For expression of z variable you comparing address of 'pa' with 'pb' forcing them to interpret as a cast char pointer , but this two pointer may have allocated at two different location in memory so they do not match and you get z=6 (i.e. false)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please try to print the address of pa and pb and c. I think pa and pb are not same.

Comment: that's what m saying , pa and pb have different address and c at different location , but value stored in pointer pa and pb referes to same address i.e. address of c .  So , 1st and 2nd expression is true while 3rd one is false

Comment: Value stored in pa and pb are different.

Comment: @Saravanan , you not getting me .  See pa and pb are two pointers , they have same value stored in their physical location i.e. address of **c**.   But they both  pa and pb  are also stored at different locations.